# Is it worth to use `select_related()` when using just one instance of a model instead of a queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'll keep it short. Say we have this database structure:

```py
class Bird(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    specie = models.CharField()

class Feather(models.Model):
    bird = models.ForeignKey(Bird)
```

And then we have some simple lines from an `APIView`:

```py
feather_id = request.query_params['feather']
feather = Feather.objects.get(pk=feather_id)

bird_name = feather.bird.name

# a lot of lines between

bird_specie = feather.bird.specie
```

Does it make any difference using:

```py
feather = Feather.objects.select_related('bird').get(pk=1)
```

instead of:

```py
feather = Feather.objects.get(pk=1)
```

in this scenario? I saw some people using `select_prefetch()` in this way and i wonder if it makes any difference, if not, which one should you use? Normally i agree that `select_prefetch()` is useful for optimization when using querysets to avoid querying each instance individually, but in this case, is it worth using it when you have just one instance in the whole `APIView`?

In my opinion the only difference is that another query is just made later on, but when talking about performance, it's the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will make a difference, but it will probably be a *very* small difference.  Selecting the related tables at the same time eliminates the time required for  additional round trips to the database, likely a few milliseconds at most.

This may only matter to you if you have higher latency connecting to the database, there are many related tables that will be fetched in turn, and/or the apiview has very high load (and every millisecond counts).

I generally use `select_related()` on single object queries, but as a stylistic choice rather than a performance choice: to indicate which other models are going to be fetched and used (explicit is better than implicit).

Comment: As for the miliseconds that are lost when connecting to the database again, i knew about them but i wondered if there were any more differences, and that "to indicate which other models are going to be fetched and used (explicit is better than implicit)" is a really good point. I guess that from now on I'll start writing single object queries like this. Thank you.